# Anylogic-Releasing agents matching certain condition from Wait object

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I have a facility producing certain products, and in the facility, there are basically 3 kinds of distinguished products. I am trying to code an action chart so that if there is an incoming order of a certain product with a certain quantity, the product is released from a "Wait" object and the released product then goes into the Delay object, which represents production.

The product is an agent with a name parameter and there are three products A, B, C. Is there a way to implement this?
Summarizing, there are three kinds of products which are all saved in one Wait object. I want to implement such that if there is an order of product A of quantity 3, then 3 of product A are released from Wait object.

[I simplified the model here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rGP9.png)
I have 2 types of products, A and B. So in the distribution center, products are stored until it is released. Product agent is used in the Distribution center flow with a string parameter "type". Order agent is used in the order flow with a string parameter "ProductType" and an integer parameter "Quantity". That is, order contains information about which product is ordered and how many of the product is ordered.

[This is where I would like to code such that only certain products ordered by an order is released with the quantity specified by the order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fD3VJ.png)
Currently, I coded like this but of course it is not able to find for example only A product in "pool".. If I do this way, I need to have a separate Wait object for each product but I would like to avoid it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an order agent that specifies the information of your order... this order will have a parameter called for instance numProductA which states how many products A the order has.

Then you can do for your order agent.

```
List <Product> productsA=findAll(waitBlock,w->w.product.type.equals("A")).subList(0,agent.numProductsA);
for(Product p : productsA){
     p.order=agent;//You will probably need to associate that product to that order so you can know later in the flow.
     waitBlock.free(p);
}
```

Here I'm assuming that you will ALWAYS have enough prodcutsA on your wait block... if that's not the case, you need to implement additional logic that might be more or less complicated depending on the case.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! Actually I forgot to say I already have a separate order process which contains another Wait block. Here, orders come in, and the orders contain product Name and product Quantity. The orders stay in another Wait block where they will be released if fulfilled. So the overall action chart logic is that it first checks the quantity in the waitblock where products stay until released, and if the quantity is not enough, available quantities are first sent, and the rest quantity triggers production.

Comment: So I guess in this case, I can first declare an integer something like int deliverQuantity = orderQuantity - StockA and put this as: List <Product> productsA=findAll(waitBlock,w->w.product.type.equals("A")).subList(0,agent.deliverQuantity)

Comment: Hello, I tried the code, and gives me error "Product cannot be resolved or is not a field" and also "agent cannot be resolved to a variable." I currently have Product agent with type parameter and Order agent with Quantity and Name parameter. I am using an action chart after checking stocks. Order has its own wait block where it stays, and products are saved in a separate wait object.

Comment: There is an event which processes this action chart of order processing, and order processing has an index. This index goes up to the size of wait object of orders. So what I tried is following:  if(order.get(index).Product == "A"){
List <Product> productsA=findAll(db,w->w.Product.type.equals("A")).subList(0,agent.Quantity);
for(Product p : productsA){
     db.free(p);}
order.free(order.get(index));
}. db is the name of the wait object for product. I think I messed up in findall part, but I could not find out where.. could you maybe give advice on this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: to be honest, I would need to see your model... I obviously used Product assuming you called your agent type Product, but if you didn't, it's impossible for me to guess... And I'm very lazy for a guess game here... so you either give an all the information that is needed, or you share the model, or accept that you are on your own..

Imagine I'm the most important person in the world, and 15 minutes of consulting with me will cost you your whole life savings... what would you do to make those 15 minutes count? how would you prepare your question in order to optimize those 15 minutes...

Comment: Hello Felipe, thanks a lot for your answer! Yes indeed, I should be more clear about my explanation. For this, I added a couple of pictures with explanations in my post, in case you have some capacity left to help. I also understand your time is important, so in any case I really appreciate for giving advice so far!

Comment: oh yes, this is a typical problem.. you need to first put all your agents that you want to free in an independent list and then use the free method over that list...  This is because when you use wait.free(i) then it's ambiguous what happens next.. if the agent is immediately free, then when you do i++ the next wait.free(i) will not refer to the agent you think.

Comment: No, I think it was misleading, I mean, I have been trying to apply your method there, I took the screen capture to show how I was doing it before I asked here which did not work (and this is why I asked here, haha). I have been using the method you showed, but I think I am screwing somewhere. I used the exact code that you gave, but only different parameters as in the model. But thank you for the advice, I think I need to put agents in a list as you said, I will keep trying. :) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for bothering so much, but I just wanted to let you know it worked!!! In the List part, List <Product> productsA=findAll(waitBlock,w->w.product.type.equals("A")).subList(0,agent.numProductsA); - for some reason w.product.type part kept giving me error, so I tried just accessing parameter directly like w.Name.equals("A"), and it worked! thank you so much, I think this code will be really useful for any application of Wait object. :D Thank you!!